# jQuery Pop-up function undynamic

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery function to open a popup when clicking on a certain link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//open popup
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
    $('.cd-popup').css("z-index", "999999999999999999999999");
});

//close popup
$('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        $('.cd-popup').css("z-index", "-999999999999999999999999");
    }
});
//close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which=='27'){
        $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
});
```

and the corresponding HTML:

```
 <!-- POPUP -->
 <div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup-container">
    </div> 
 </div> 
 <!-- POPUP -->

 <a class="cd-popup-trigger"> <!-- Trigger -->
```

Now, the problem is, the jQuery code above works for **one** popup only. Without having to copy these jQuery lines over and over again each time, does anybody know how to use this function for more than one popup?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way:

Script

```
function openPopup(id)
{
 $(id).show();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){


//close popup
$('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

//close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which=='27'){
        $('.cd-popup').hide();
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- POPUP 1-->
 <div id="popup1" class="cd-popup" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup-container">
    </div> 
 </div> 
 <!-- POPUP 1 -->

<!-- POPUP 2-->
 <div id="popup2" class="cd-popup" role="alert">
    <div class="cd-popup-container">
    </div> 
 </div> 
 <!-- POPUP 2 -->

<a onclick="openPopup('#popup1')">Show 1st</a>
<a onclick="openPopup('#popup2')">Show 2nd</a>
```